# Powermock: NoClassDefFoundError when trying to mock static classes

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I'm trying to understand how to use Powermock.
I'm trying to realize the example of Static method mocking [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage).

I created this code based on the example above.

I however get a NoClassDefFoundError when trying to run the test.

I don't know what exactly is causing this error as it is mostly copy pasted code.

```
// imports redacted

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Static.class)
public class YourTestCase {
    @Test
    public void testMethodThatCallsStaticMethod() throws Exception {
        // mock all the static methods in a class called "Static"
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Static.class);
        // use Mockito to set up your expectation
        PowerMockito.when(Static.class, "firstStaticMethod", any()).thenReturn(true);
        PowerMockito.when(Static.class, "secondStaticMethod", any()).thenReturn(321);

        // execute your test
        new ClassCallStaticMethodObj().execute();

        // Different from Mockito, always use PowerMockito.verifyStatic() first
        // to start verifying behavior
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.times(2));
        // IMPORTANT:  Call the static method you want to verify
        Static.firstStaticMethod(anyInt());


        // IMPORTANT: You need to call verifyStatic() per method verification,
        // so call verifyStatic() again
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(); // default times is once
        // Again call the static method which is being verified
        Static.secondStaticMethod();

        // Again, remember to call verifyStatic()
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.never());
        // And again call the static method.
        Static.thirdStaticMethod();
    }
}

class Static {
    public static boolean firstStaticMethod(int foo) {
        return true;
    }

    public static int secondStaticMethod() {
        return 123;
    }

    public static void thirdStaticMethod() {
    }
}

class ClassCallStaticMethodObj {
    public void execute() {
        boolean foo = Static.firstStaticMethod(2);
        int bar = Static.secondStaticMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PowerMock 1.6.6 seems to be incompatible with Mockito 2.7

I've made some changes to your `pom.xml`. First I changed powermock version:

```
<powermock.version>1.7.0RC2</powermock.version>
```

Then I changed `powermock-api-mockito` to `powermock-api-mockito2` (the first one didn't work, it seems to be incompatible with Mockito 2.7):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This solved the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

---

Anyway, I still had to change this to make it work: instead of `PowerMockito.when()`, you should use `Mockito.when()`:

```
Mockito.when(Static.firstStaticMethod(anyInt())).thenReturn(true);
Mockito.when(Static.secondStaticMethod()).thenReturn(321);
```

Comment: That sadly doesn't fix the NoClassDefFoundError error.

Comment: How is your classpath set?

Comment: Does the stacktrace of `NoClassDefFoundError` show you the class that's missing?

Comment: [Here's](https://pastebin.com/zws47WgM) the error message. I think it is WhiteboxImpl.

Comment: I don't explicitly set my classpath. I just have this [pom.xml](https://pastebin.com/GHRgdmy2) and run mvn test.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. I can't believe that the solution was this simple.

Comment: @Hugo This helped me with the `NoClassDefFoundError`, however I am still having a `MissingMethodInvocationException`. Even though according to documentation, I am doing `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)` and `@PrepareForTest(MyClass::class)` on the test class, and `mockStatic(MyClass::class.java)` (kotlin) and `when(MyClass.myMethod()).thenReturn("the-value")` in the test method. Any ideas why is this? I am using Mockito 2.8.9 and PowerMock 1.7.0. Thanks.

Comment: @EdisonSpencer With only this info, it's hard to say what's wrong (specially because I don't know kotlin). I suggest you to write another question detailing your problem. Sorry, I wish I could help you more on that.

Comment: Thank you @Hugo, but I decided after talking to a colleague that there are better approaches to mocking static fields. So I am testing this without using powermock at all.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above,
The reason is version compatibility. I am using mockito 3 (3.3.3)
It solved for me by declaring dependancies for powermockito as below.

```
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
```

2.0.7 is the latest version as of now